# I have a python tuple of namedtuples. Is there a way to access individual members other than by indexing or unpacking them?

Tags: python

I have a python 3.5 tuple where a typical structure of a data item is something like this.

```
item = (PosixPath('/mnt/dson/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/funtoons.mp3'), tagtypes(txt=False, word=False, ebook=False, image=False, exe=False, iso=False, zip=False, raw=False, audio=True, music=True, photoshop=False, video=False, src=False, geek=False, pdf=False, appledouble=False, dot=False), fileinfo(size=13229145, datetime=1333848240.0))
```

This describes a common file on my Linux filesystem. If I want to know the size
of the given file, I can access it with something like this --- 
`item[2].size`. Similarly, logic to grab the tags describing the file's contents would use code like --- `item[1].music`, etc..

It seems on the face of it, with each object being unique in the tuple
that if you wanted to access one of the members, you should be able to
drill down in the tuple and do something like item.fileinfo.size. All of
the information to select the correct item from the tuple is deducible
to the interpreter.  However, if you do attempt something like
`item.fileinfo.size` you will get (almost expectedly) an attribute error.

I could create a namedtuple of namedtuples but that has a bit of a code smell to it.

I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic way to access the members of the tuple other than by indexing or unpacking.  Is there some kind of
shorthand notation such that you convey to the interpreter which one of
the tuple's elements you must be referencing (because none of the other
options will fit the pattern)?

This is kind of a hard thing to explain and I'm famous for leaving out
critical parts. So if more info is needed by the first responders, please
let me know and I'll try and describe the idea more fully.

Comment: Personally, I would use a class for this.

Comment: Or even a dictionary.

Comment: namedtuple is a class.  that is each instance of named tuple is a class

Comment: This is definitely when you'd either build the container a class or a namedtuple. I'd strongly recommend Dmitry's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You really think doing this:

```
Item = namedtuple('Item', 'PosixPath tagtypes fileinfo')

item = Item(PosixPath('/mnt/dson/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/funtoons.mp3'), tagtypes(txt=False, word=False, ebook=False, image=False, exe=False, iso=False, zip=False, raw=False, audio=True, music=True, photoshop=False, video=False, src=False, geek=False, pdf=False, appledouble=False, dot=False), fileinfo(size=13229145, datetime=1333848240.0))
```

is not worth it if it lets you do `item.fileinfo.size` AND `item[2].size` ?  That's pretty clean.  It avoids creating classes by hand and gives you all the functionality in a clear and concise manner.  Seems like pretty good python to me.

Comment: actually, yeah.  you are right.  I'll remove the obvious bug.

Comment: Just checking. I know some strongly typed languages allow that because the compiler knows that `Item` has an attribute `fileinfo` that is of type `fileinfo`, so you can just throw arguments to its constructor there. I couldn't imagine Python being able to know that.

Comment: You are right, well, conceivably the implementation of namedtuple could try to match known namedtuples or even known types to its own arguments.  But it would make it too difficult to guess what's really going on underneath for the user of a numedtuple,  And reducing readability is not something Python would go for.